# Dependent dropdown not working Mysql Php - Returns `Undefined`

Tags: php, mysqli

I have two dropdowns generating from MySQL database. The second dropdown is based on the first dropdown select option.

The problem is that, I am unable to generate the second dropdown data.

**I am getting the second dropdown values as `Undefined`. But the number of values that should come in the second dropdown is correct.**

Please suggest where am I doing wrong. Thanks.

**Below are my codes:**

Index.php (connection)

```
<?php  
//Create the connection  

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","echodeve_mfb_temp") or die("Some error occurred during connection " . mysqli_error($con));  

// Write query

$strSQL = "SELECT bp_id, bp_name FROM mfb_billing";

// Execute the query.

$query = mysqli_query($con, $strSQL);


// Close the connection
//mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Index.php (Script)

```
  <script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#item_1").change(function () {   

      var group_id = $(this).val();

       $.ajax({
            type: "POST", 
            url: "dropdown_select.php?item_1_id=" + group_id, 
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                //Clear options corresponding to earlier option of first dropdown
                $('select#item_2').empty(); 
                $('select#item_2').append('<option value="0">Select Option</option>');
                //Populate options of the second dropdown
                $.each( data, function(i, val){    
                    $('select#item_2').append('<option value="' + val.hospital_id + '">' + val.hospital_name + '</option>');
                });
                $('select#item_2').focus();
            },
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('select#item_2').empty();
                $('select#item_2').append('<option value="0">Loading...</option>');
            },
            error: function(){
                $('select#item_2').attr('disabled', true);
                $('select#item_2').empty();
                $('select#item_2').append('<option value="0">No Options</option>');
            }
        })  

    }); 
});

</script>

  </head>
```

Index.php (HTML)

```
  <body>
 <label id="item_1_label" for="item_1" class="label">#1:</label>
<select id="item_1" name="item_1" />
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <?php

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 
            echo '<option value="'.$row['bp_id'].'">'.$row['bp_name'].'</option>'."\n";       
        }
     ?>
</select>

<label id="item_2_label" for="item_2" class="label">#2:</label>
<select id="item_2" name="item_2" />                        
</select>



   </body>
```

dropdown_select.php (Processing PHP)

```
    <?php

$item_1_id = $_GET['item_1_id'];

//Create the connection  

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","echodeve_mfb_temp") or die("Some error occurred during connection " . mysqli_error($con));  

// Write query

$strSQL = "SELECT hospital_id, hospital_name FROM mfb_hospital WHERE bp_id = $item_1_id";

// Execute the query.

$query = mysqli_query($con, $strSQL);

$return_arr = array(); 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 

    $row_array = array("name" => $row['hospital_name'], 
                       "id" => $row['hospital_id']); 

    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);     
}

echo json_encode($return_arr);

?>
```

Comment: Can you show me $query string ?

Comment: in dropdown_select.php  `$query = mysqli_query($con, $strSQL);`

Comment: After $query = mysqli_query($con, $strSQL);                                     print_r( $query ); check this, let me know what it is giving ?

Comment: this file gets a data and then run query using it.... How can I print result of that query.... I mean I call this from another page right?

Comment: after print_r( $query ); add die; It will stop executing script further and it will show you $query.

Comment: I got it working to some extent. the second dropdown now shows values as undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP error exactly tells you what is going wrong and as [manual says](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php): *Returns FALSE on failure* .

Since your error describres $query as *boolean given* you have to check several thing on your own.

First echo your $strSQL and see if it's proper query, then try to execute it directly on database. There maybe several things, like inproper name of column.

Also, you are returning:

```
$row_array = array("name" => $row['hospital_name'], 
                       "id" => $row['hospital_id']);
```

Yet in javascript you are doing:

```
$.each( data, function(i, val){    
    $('select#item_2').append('<option value="' + val.hospital_id + '">' + val.hospital_name + '</option>');
});
```

***try this:***

```
$.each( data, function(i, val){    
    $('select#item_2').append('<option value="' + val.id + '">' + val.name + '</option>');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I got it working to some extent. the second dropdown now shows values as undefined. Can you point me to the right direction please?

Comment: I've updated my answer, try to iterate through same array keys as returned from your php

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I had solved it much before you answered and exactly the same way. But as your suggestion pointed me to the right direction, I will accept your answer as the correct one. Thanks again.